# How to make dynamic graph with rickshaw without refreshing the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, rickshaw

I want to make dynamic graph, which always gives fresh data without refreshing the whole page. In the following example they build the graph on random data. But in this problem data is not fresh only refreshing of browser will get fresh data. [Please see this link](http://code.runnable.com/UlbPx4tJHRIWAABB/rickshaw-examples-graph-with-interactive-hover-details) for ajax request I am using reference from here [please see it](https://github.com/shutterstock/rickshaw/blob/master/examples/ajax.html)

I copied the whole code below. I want to make graph which is movable, like real time update some like [flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/), But don't want to use flot, but rickshaw.

```
    <!doctype>
<head>
        <title>rickShaw greaph examples</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../src/css/graph.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../src/css/legend.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../src/css/detail.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/lines.css">

    <script src="../vendor/d3.v3.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../rickshaw.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="chart_container" style="margin:0px auto;width:660px;">
    <div id="chart"></div>
        <div id="legend_container">
            <div id="smoother" title="Smoothing"></div>
            <div id="legend"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="slider"></div>
</div>

<script>
       // set up our data series with 50 random data points
        var seriesData = [ [], [], [] ];
        var random = new Rickshaw.Fixtures.RandomData(150);

        for (var i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
            random.addData(seriesData);
        }

var ajaxGraph = new Rickshaw.Graph.Ajax( {

    element: document.getElementById("chart"),
    width: 400,
    height: 200,
    renderer: 'line',
    series: [
        {
            name: 'New York',
                        data: seriesData[0],
            color: '#c05020',
        }, {
            name: 'London',
                        data: seriesData[0],
            color: '#30c020',
        }, {
            name: 'Tokyo',
                        data: seriesData[0],
            color: '#6060c0'
        }
    ]
} );
ajaxGraph.render();

var hoverDetail = new Rickshaw.Graph.HoverDetail( {
            graph: graph
        } );

        var legend = new Rickshaw.Graph.Legend( {
            graph: graph,
            element: document.getElementById('legend')

        } );

        var shelving = new Rickshaw.Graph.Behavior.Series.Toggle( {
            graph: graph,
            legend: legend
        } );


        var axes = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Time( {
            graph: graph
        } );
        axes.render();
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: @thisOneGuy, Thanks for reply. Could you tell me how to use Ajax here

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
var seriesData = [ [], [], [] ];
var random = new Rickshaw.Fixtures.RandomData(150);

for (var i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
    random.addData(seriesData);
}
```

Do an ajax call within some interval of time and update the chart's data series.  Sort of like this (taken form their other example using ajax) here is the example I used http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/ajax/index.html

```
data = [];

$.plot("#placeholder", data, options);

function fetchData() {

  function onDataReceived(series) {

    // Load all the data in one pass; if we only got partial
    // data we could merge it with what we already have.

    data = [ series ];
    $.plot("#placeholder", data, options);
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: "data-eu-gdp-growth-" + iteration + ".json",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: onDataReceived
  });

  setTimeout(fetchData, 1000);
}

setTimeout(fetchData, 1000);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for reply, I saw the link you have given, It is  not fetching the real time data. And there is no source code..

Comment: You can view source of page and all the code is in there